# Add just one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with this code by clicking the + I need add only one option element not more. If I Click on the button `test01` more times and I want to add in previous the + button element option only one going to add them to me more.

```js
var y=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#test01").click(function(){
  var x=y++;  
  var plustypdiv = document.createElement("div"); plustypdiv.id="plustypdiv"+x; 
  var plustyp = document.createElement("input"); plustyp.type="button"; plustyp.value="+"; plustyp.id=""+x; plustyp.className="plustyp";
  
  document.body.appendChild(plustypdiv);
  plustypdiv.appendChild(plustyp);
  
 $(".plustyp").click(function (){
  
 

 var typi = ["0","0","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"];
  var plutypdiv2 = document.getElementById("plustypdiv"+this.id);
     var tzp2 = document.createElement("select"); tzp2.className="tiphryd"; 
   for (i=0;i<=11;i++){
  var opt= document.createElement("option"); opt.innerHTML= typi[i]; opt.value=i; 
     plutypdiv2.appendChild(tzp2);
  tzp2.appendChild(opt);};
  
  }); 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="test01" value="test01">
```

Comment: I understand English is not your native language, but you have to try a bit harder than that. It simply makes no sense as it is

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant is this:

"When i click the `test01` button, a new `+` button should appear. When i click a `+` button, one *and only one* select element should appear next to it."

If that's the case, this code should do the trick:

(also if that's the case, please reword your question)

```js
;(function($){
  "use strict";

  var addRow = function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#shadow .row').clone(true,true).appendTo('form#f');
  };

  var addSelect = function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest('.row').find('select').length > 0) {
      //  do nothing, because there already is a select element here  
    } else {
      $('#shadow select').clone(true,true).prop('disabled',false).insertAfter(this);  
    }
  };

  $('button.addrow').on('click',addRow);
  $('button.addselect').on('click',addSelect);

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="f">

  <button class="addrow">test01</button>

</form>  

<!-- poor man's shadow DOM -->
<div hidden="hidden" id="shadow">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="addselect">+</button>
  </div>
  <select disabled="disabled">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
  </select>
</div>
```